# Парсинг аргументов командной строки в формате ключ=значение с учетом синтаксиса Java

Tags: java, парсер, map, командная-строка

Пытаюсь разобрать командную строку с использованием маппинга. Строка должна иметь приблизительно следующий вид:

> -file=simple.txt -command=add -name=John -surname=Doe -age=18

Делаю так:

```
private Map<String, String> parse(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2){
        if (i + 1 < args.length){
            parameters.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}
```

Все получается нормально. Вот только синтаксис в сроке не учитывается вообще и, строка выглядит так: 
file simple.txt command add name John surname Doe age 18.
Я недавно занимаюсь Java и не совсем понимаю, как можно добавить в эту строку правильный синтаксис... Вопрос в том, как правильно сделать парсинг с учетом синтаксиса строки. Буду благодарен за помощь.
Вот код, который у меня есть. Класс модели:

```
public class Person implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = -8319950653022309296L;

private static AtomicInteger nextID = new AtomicInteger(0);

private int id;
private String name;
private String surname;
private int age;
private String email;

private Person(int id, String name, String surname, int age, String email) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
    this.surname = surname;
    this.age = age;
    this.email = email;
}

public Person(String name, String surname, int age, String address) {
    this(nextID.getAndIncrement(), name, surname, age, address);
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public String getSurname() {
    return surname;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public static PersonBuilder newBuilder() {
    return new PersonBuilder();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "\n\nID: " + getId() + "\nName: " + getName() + "\nSurname: " + getSurname() + "\nAge: " + getAge() + "\nEmail: " + getEmail();
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (this == o) return true;
    if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
    Person person = (Person) o;
    return Objects.equals(name, person.name) &&
            Objects.equals(surname, person.surname) &&
            Objects.equals(age, person.age) &&
            Objects.equals(email, person.email);
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(name, surname, age, email);
}
```

Класс парсинга:

```
public class Parser {

public void show(String[] args) throws RuntimeException {
    Map<String, String> params = new Parser().parse(args);

    for (String arg : args) {
        switch (arg) {
            case "add":
                AddCommand add = new AddCommand();
                add.execute(params);
                break;
            case "parse":
                ViewAllCommand view = new ViewAllCommand();
                view.execute(params);
                break;
            case "replace":
                ReplaceCommand rc = new ReplaceCommand();
                rc.execute(params);
                break;
            case "find":
                FindCommand fc = new FindCommand();
                fc.execute(params);
                break;
            case "clear":
                ClearCommand cc = new ClearCommand();
                cc.execute(params);
                break;
        }
    }
}

private Map<String, String> parse(String[] args) {
    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < args.length; i += 2){
        if (i + 1 < args.length){
            parameters.put(args[i], args[i + 1]);
        }
    }
    return parameters;
}}
```

Интерфейс с метедом выполнения комманд:

```
public interface Command {
void execute(Map<String, String> params);}
```

Класс для команды Add:

```
public class AddCommand implements Command {

@Override
public void execute(Map<String, String> params) {
    try {
        Person person = newBuilder().withName(params.get("name")).withSurname(params.get("surname"))
                .withAge(Integer.parseInt(params.get("age"))).withEmail(params.get("email")).build();

        System.out.println(person.toString() + "\n");
        params.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.printf("flag: %s - value: %s\n", k, v));
        DataFile dataFile = new DataFile(params.get("file"));
        dataFile.save(person);

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Age should be a positive integer");
    }
}}
```

Класс Main:

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) throws RuntimeException{
    Parser parser = new Parser();
    parser.show(args);
}}
```

Ну и, класс для работы с файлом:

```
public class DataFile {
private File file;
private List<Person> people = new ArrayList<>();

public DataFile(String fileName) {
    this.file = new File(fileName);
}

public void save(Person person) {
    try(BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file, true))) {
        writer.write(person.getName()+ "\r" + person.getSurname() + "\r" + person.getAge() + "\r" + person.getEmail() + "\r\n\r\n");
    } catch(IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    loadAll();
    writeToJson();
}

public List<Person> loadAll() {
    try(BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        String name;
        while((name = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            Person person = new Person(name, reader.readLine(), Integer.parseInt(reader.readLine()), reader.readLine());
            people.add(person);
            reader.readLine();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
    return people;
}

public void writeToJson(){
    try (BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("data_file.json"))) {
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        bw.write(gson.toJson(people));
        bw.flush();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}}
```

Comment: Меня пробел перед равно смущает, он точно должен там быть? Синтаксис аргументов чувствительных к таким вещам, мб там `-file=simple.txt -command=add -name=John -surname=Doe -age=18`? И еще, вы просто пытаетесь такую строку разобрать, или ее передаете в приложение при запуске и получаете тот `args` через `public static void main(String[] args)`?

Comment: @gil9red Нет, пробел не существенен, - это я "погорячился" с пробелом. Пользователь вводит эту строку и, каждое значение, соответствующее ключу, сохраняется в файл и в Json. Команды в строке (собственно, как и другие значения) могут меняться на remove, clear, replace, find и т.д.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вы передаете строку `-file=simple.txt -command=add -name=John -surname=Doe -age=18 --name2=dfdfsf` в командную строку при запуске, то получите ее в `args`.

Пример:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(args)); // [-file=simple.txt, -command=add, -name=John, -surname=Doe, -age=18, --name2=dfdfsf]
    
    Map<String, String> parameters = new LinkedHashMap<>();

    for (String arg : args) {
        String[] parts = arg.split("=", 2);
        String key = parts[0];
        if (key.startsWith("--")) {
            key = key.substring(2);
        } else {
            key = key.substring(1);
        }
        String value = parts[1];

        parameters.put(key, value);
    }

    System.out.println(parameters);  // {file=simple.txt, command=add, name=John, surname=Doe, age=18, name2=dfdfsf}
}
```

---

**PS**

Пример сохранения в файл:

```
    try (PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter("filename.txt")) {
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> pair : parameters.entrySet()) {
            out.println(pair.getKey() + " -> " + pair.getValue());
        }
    }
```

Comment: Вроде все логично, - но не получается...( Не сохраняет в файл. Я сейчас напишу больше кода, который у меня есть, - может подскажете, что не так...

Comment: @Alex эмм, какой файл? Вопрос был про парсинг параметров командной строки, и именно об этом ответ

Comment: @Regent Ну, просто парсинг делается не ради самого парсинга), а чтобы что-то с этой строкой потом сделать... В данном случае разобранная на ключ-значение строка должна сохранять в файл значения, соответствующие полям класса модели...

Comment: @Alex, добавил. Если нужно без посредников, то оформляйте его в `for (String arg : args) {`

Comment: @Alex понятно, что задача у вас больше, чем просто парсинг. Однако StackOverflow ведь работает в концепции "один конкретный вопрос/проблема - конкретные ответы/решения этого вопроса"

Comment: @Regent Да, согласен. Задан вопрос - получен ответ. Все правильно.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(args[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В чем проблема ???

Ответ удалю. В коментарии нельзя добавить картинку

Comment: То, что Вы пишете - понятно. Но, мне нужно, чтобы строка разбиралась на пары ключ-значение. Т.е., например -имя(это ключ) =Вася(это значение). Пользователь, введя ключ и соответствующее ему значение, сохранит все это в файл (ну, или Json).

Comment: и нужно сделать, чтобы парсер искал слова(ключи), которые начинаются с тире и слова(значения), которые начинаются с равно ???

Comment: Да, совершенно верно!))) Кроме того, еще нужно было бы, чтобы можно было использовать "полную" и "сокращенную" формы, - т.е. если одно тире, то -n, если двойное тире, то --name и т.д.

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите [Apache Commons CLI](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-cli/), там уже всё "автоматизировано".

Comment: Спасибо!) С этой библиотекой я уже приложение сделал. Там действительно ничего этого не надо. Но, в данном случае, надо все сделать "вручную". Многие библиотеки Cli не потокобезопасны и их не хотят применять.